# Getting issue while deploye Azure protocol gateway to cloud as worker role

Tags: azure, iot

I am trying to configure IOT protocol gateway (MQTT protocol) on azure as a worker role. I have follow all the step mention by microsoft [Deploying Cloud Sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-protocol-gateway)
.But I am doing same deployment process using power shell.But deployment process failed at last stage.[Please check image for more details on power shell command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TMns.png).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with the protocol gateway but it looks like the errors you're running into are just related to powershell: I think you need to enclose the connection string in quotes (because it contains special characters such as ';').

Also, just in case, I should mention: if you just want to use MQTT, you don't need the protocol gateway at all. An Azure IoT Hub instance "speaks" MQTT natively.

Comment: I have tried but it's not working. I am configure IOT protocol gateway to check it's implementation with default mqtt protocol. But in actual scenario I will use this gateway to implement node-comm protocol that will used by my legacy device which only communication through nodecomm.

Comment: understood, that sounds like a good scenario. I'm positive the problem is with how the script is invoked from the command line: quotes around the password section (Before HostName and after the shared access key last character) and also I don't think you should have brackets the subscription and vmcount arguments. Feel free to post a copy/pasted log of the error here if you'd like, just edit out the keys first (you left some in your first screenshot, you should change them)

Comment: I have tried with that solution. But it did not work for me. Please check this image for more detail http://prntscr.com/aqs0cg .

Comment: Right but this is progress. As you can see, the error is different now, and points at the last arguments. In this case, it's because the last arguments are not formatted properly. Take your third attempt on this last screenshot, and remove the square brackets '[' and ']' around the subscription and vmcount arguments